# How to handle nested iframe using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Consider i'm having a html page which contains following HTML Code

```
<div>    
  <iframe src="some_src_link">    
    <iframe src="some_src_link2">   
      //code..
    </iframe>
  </iframe>    
</div>
```

So i want iterate all the iframe inside the HTML page when page loads.
As i need to set the index attribute to each iframe. Some thing like below HTML Code

```
    <div>    
      <iframe src="some_src_link" index="0">    
        <iframe src="some_src_link2" index="0-0">   
          <iframe src="some_src_link3" index="0-0-0">   
          </iframe>
        </iframe>
      </iframe> 
<iframe src="some_src_link4" index="1">    
        <iframe src="some_src_link5" index="1-0">   
          <iframe src="some_src_link6" index="1-0-0">   
          </iframe>
        </iframe>
      </iframe>    
    </div>
//INDEX --parentIframe-childIframe-grandchildIframe
```

I tired with simple jquery method

```
$("iframe").map(function(index,iframe){
        if(self == top){ //check for parent iframe

             $(iframe).attr('index',index);
         }else{

             $(iframe).attr('index',index);
         } 
     return iframe;
   });
```

Can able to apply only index such as below code.

```
<div>    
  <iframe src="some_scr_link" index="0">    
    <iframe src="some_scr_link2" index="0">   
      <iframe src="some_scr_link2" index="0">   
      </iframe>
    </iframe>
  </iframe>    
</div>
```

My question how can i iterate like tree structure respectively to its parent iframe and detect whether iframe is a parent or child or grand Child.
And setting index attribute like //iframe INDEX --parentIframe-childIframe-grandchildIframe  so on.Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: Are all these links same domain as you web site?

Comment: No links are from different domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the iteration of each iframe in the document. The way is correct, but you need the check whether the iframe is parent or child or grandchild.

```
    function getFrameIndex() {
  let frameINDEX = "";
  let currentWindow = window;
  let currentParentWindow;
  while (currentWindow !== window.top) { // check if parent or not
    currentParentWindow = currentWindow.parent;
    for (let iframeID = 0; iframeID < currentParentWindow.frames.length; iframeID ++)
      if (currentParentWindow.frames[iframeID ] === currentWindow) {
        frameINDEX = ":" + iframeID + frameINDEX ;
        currentWindow = currentParentWindow;
        break;
      }
  }
  frameINDEX = "Parent" + frameINDEX;
  return frameINDEX ; 
}
```

Hope this may help to starts

Comment: How to add as attribute in iframe

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is to change iframe content. Well fortunately you can't. You cannot have access to cross origin domains in an iframe. If the domain blocks Cross-origin request you can do nothing about it.

Comment: No i'm trying to add attribute to the iframe tag, not changing the content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with this HTML structure, but whatever it is you'll need to find a different approach, because nested iframe tags aren't possible.  This is invalid HTML (or, perhaps, technically-valid-but-useless HTML):

```
<div>    
  <iframe src="some_src_link">    
    <iframe src="some_src_link2">   
      //code..
    </iframe>
  </iframe>    
</div>
```

The innerHTML of an iframe tag is only displayed in browsers that do not support iframes. Given the above HTML, the page at `some_src_link` would be displayed, and the tag attempting to embed `some_src_link2` would simply be ignored by all modern browsers, because it's in a portion of the page that will be replaced by the iframe's src content.

If any browser that doesn't support iframes still exists, then in that browser naturally enough all the iframes would be skipped over, and their innerHTML would be displayed (so, in this case, the string "//code.." and some surrounding whitespace.)

I can't imagine why you would want nested iframes in the first place, but if you do, the page at `some_src_link` would need to contain the iframe pointed at `some_src_link2`; you can't set the "grandchild" page directly from the parent.

Comment: I know  the given HTML  is invalid. But what i'm trying to make you understand is that a HTML PAGE having multiple nested iframes

Comment: An HTML page having multiple nested iframes won't work. The topmost iframe will load and the nested ones will be ignored.

Comment: HTML with  iframe contains src="some.html" , some.html contains iframe src="some2.html" ...I think you got it :

Comment: That would be valid, yes, as I described in the answer above.  I don't know what you're trying to say in these comments, can you please use complete sentences and explain more clearly what you're asking for?

Comment: HTML page contains multiple iframes and each iframe source page contains multiple iframes. So i need to iterate all the iframe and set index attribute to the each iframe

Comment: Ok. (For future reference, it would save a lot of time and confusion if the code in your question actually matched what you’re asking about.). Since you’ve indicated that the framed pages are on different domains, you won’t be able to do this (without CORS access you can’t modify the contents of a third party frame, which is what you’d have to do to add those attributes.

Comment: But anyhow, as i told jquery can able to add index to all the iframes in the page using this code  //------------        $("iframe").map(function(index,iframe){
        if(self == top){ //check for parent iframe

             $(iframe).attr('index',index);
         }else{

             $(iframe).attr('index',index);
         } 
     return iframe;
   });

Comment: Go ahead and give that a try. You'll find it will set the attributes on the iframe tags in the parent window, yes, but will not modify those contained inside  the framed pages (because they are separate pages with their own separate js context, even before taking CORS into account.)

Comment: Yes had a try Daniel sir, But getting cant able to set the index as said above in my question.   //INDEX --parentIframe-childIframe-grandchildIframe